# Making a ajax request to server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im making an application similar to JSbin / JS fiddle. I want to make an ajax request to the server to update my database when the user clicks on the save code button with the values that the user has typed in  the textarea.
Could someone help me out.  I don't know whats wrong , my database doesn't get updated with the textarea content .I would like to use only pure javascript

```
MY HTML code




<main>
  <form id="myform" method="post">
    <div id="bodyContainer">
      <div class="Panels" id="HtmlPanel">
        <textarea
          id="html"
          name="html"
          placeholder=" ENTER HTML CODE HERE"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="Panels hidden" id="CssPanel">
        <textarea
          id="css"
          name="css"
          placeholder=" ENTER CSS CODE HERE"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="Panels hidden" id="JsPanel">
        <textarea
          id="js"
          name="js"
          placeholder=" ENTER JAVASCRIPT HERE"
        ></textarea>
           </div>
              <iframe class="Panels" id="OutputPanel" placeholder="Output"></iframe>
           </div>
          </form>
          </main>

       button HTML:<button onclick="SaveCode()" type="submit" id="save-code-btn" name="save-code">
        Save Code
      </button>

JAVASCRIPT:

  function SaveCode(){  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    const requestData = {
    html: document.getElementById("html").value,
    css: document.getElementById("css").value,
    js: document.getElementById("js").value,
  };
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Check if the request is compete and was successful
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        alert("Succesful")
    }
};
    request.open("post", "SaveCode.php",true);
    request.setRequestHeader(
      "Content-type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );
    request.send("html="+requestData.html);
  }


PHP CODE(SaveCode.php)
  <?PHP
  session_start();
   include('DBconnection.php');
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   $html = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['html']);
   $query= 'UPDATE users details SET html="'.$html.'"WHERE 
     id="'.$_SESSION['id'].'"';
     $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     if($result){
     echo "Success";
      }else{
      echo "Fail";
       }   


      }
       ?>
```

Comment: one thing that I would verify is that on EVERY PHP page you have `session_start();` at the top

Comment: yup i realized that too, but still the problem persists

Comment: Did you checked that data are well sent ? Do you have any Exception triggered ? An error message in Javascript console ?

Comment: You don't actually execute the query anywhere, you just create a variable to contain it. When you do execute it, will the missing space between the closing quote and WHERE stop it working?

Comment: You really need to look at prepared statements instead of escaping the post string.

Comment: @GrégoryC   i  had console logged the texarea value  before.But after sending it , I didn't verify it. Could you help me out?

Comment: @droopsnoot :  i executed the query, a silly mistake on my part but the problem still remains.

Comment: @droopsnoot Actually this is my college project I'm working on right now so we are not thought about prepared statements

Comment: u cannot "LIMIT" an update-query, therefore your statement fails... maybe 

Comment: @KevinRodrigues, OK, if it's a college project then you have to write it the way you have been taught, just remember that if you come to do anything in real life, you'll get no thanks for sticking to those old ways.

Comment: I see you've now added a line of code to execute the query. Does it execute, or does it return `false`? You should check the return as a matter of course.

Comment: @droopsnoot I've added  a echo  to show if query is executed or no but it doesn't show me anything, but I do get an alert which I have set up when state changes using onreadyState change.....i updated the code

Comment: Your onreadystatechange() function only displays something if it was successful. What about displaying something if it was not?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it local machine you should run your files on some php server, like Openserver or lamp.

And try to change your url to something like that:

http://localhost/SaveCode.php

http://127.0.0.1/SaveCode.php

Hope this helps you if you are testing on local machine =)

Comment: Ya ,im doin it on a xampp server